# Why such a huge difference in Z3 solving time for almost the same query?

Tags: z3, smt

Adding `(push 1)` just before the check-sat call
speeds up the solving by ~10x (70s. vs 700s.)
Why?:) How to output the tactics that z3 used in both cases?

More general question:
Is there "How To" or a tool to find best parameters for particular smt queries?

The query with `push` is [here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/444947/posts/smt_by_elli_incr.smt2), and the [log](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/444947/posts/stats_push)(starts with `(smt.simplifier-done)`)
(the same query) without `push` is [here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/444947/posts/smt_by_elli_non_incr.smt2) and the [log](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/444947/posts/stats_no_push).
thanks!

Comment: Try to use verbose output -v:10 will show tactics used by the non-incremental mode.